# How to get Jenkins to send JsUnit report if a failure occurs?

Tags: javascript, maven, jenkins, jsunit

Below is the segment of pom.xml that Jankins runs but it doesn't send in the e-mail the error that occurred. Did anybody get this to work.

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>de.berlios.jsunit</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsunit-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>test</id>
                    <configuration>
                        <sourceDirectory>./WebContent/jsunit</sourceDirectory>
                        <sources>
                            <source>blah.js</source>

                        </sources>
                        <testSourceDirectory>./WebContent/jsunit</testSourceDirectory>
                        <reportsDirectory>${project.build.directory}/surefire-reports</reportsDirectory>
                        <testSuites>
                            <testSuite>
                                <name>SampleSuite</name>
                                <type>TESTCASES</type>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>blah_test.js</include>
                                </includes>
                            </testSuite>
                        </testSuites>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jsunit-test</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 1):

Jenkins won't do this by default, but if you use the [Extended Email plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin) you can configure your build emails to include any data you like from the console output.  You might also want to look at [these examples](http://software-engineer-tips-and-tricks.blogspot.com/2011/10/jenkins-jelly-examples.html) of using Jelly templates to format the emails.